# Unable to give Input Value to input field using childNodes(DOM)

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have to give input using dom only i.e with the childNodes.I cant use document.getElement By ID to the first name and all other input input fields.This is what I tried so far.Its showing the value I set using DOM in console but not in the input field.

```js
var inp=document.getElementById("form-content");
inp.childNodes[0].value="IsatAvalue";
console.log(inp.childNodes[0].value);
```

```html
<div>
    <h1>DOM</h1>
    <div id="form-content" class="content"
    ><br><label for="first-name">First Name</label>
    <br><input type="text" id="first-name"/>
    <label for="last-name"><br>Last Name</label>
    <br><input type="text" id="last-name"/>
    <label for="email"><br>Email</label>
    <br><input type="text" id="email" />
    </div>
    <div id="main-content" class="content">
    <p class="render">First Name : Alex</p>
    <p class="render" id="lastName">Last Name: Bank</p>
    <p class="render"> Email : alexbank@example.com</p>
    <p class="render"> Country : Pakistan </p>
    <p class="render"> contact : +92 300 1234567</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to change? Which value needs to be modified?

Comment: I need to change the input empty field to give it a value from the dom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`childNodes` will include *all* child nodes of the element, including text nodes.  (For example, your `inp.childNodes[0]` actually refers to the first `<br>`.

You absolutely do not want to use an array index on childNodes to identify form inputs; your code would be terribly fragile, and would break basically any time someone edited the HTML (simply adding some text between nodes would be enough to change the index numbers.)

You could improve on this slightly by selecting only the elements of the particular tag type you want:

```js
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('#form-content input'); // select all inputs inside #form-content
inputs[0].value="first name"
console.log(inputs[0].value)
```

```html
<div>
    <h1>DOM</h1>
    <div id="form-content" class="content"
    ><br><label for="first-name">First Name</label>
    <br><input type="text" id="first-name"/>
    <label for="last-name"><br>Last Name</label>
    <br><input type="text" id="last-name"/>
    <label for="email"><br>Email</label>
    <br><input type="text" id="email" />
    </div>
    <div id="main-content" class="content">
    <p class="render">First Name : Alex</p>
    <p class="render" id="lastName">Last Name: Bank</p>
    <p class="render"> Email : alexbank@example.com</p>
    <p class="render"> Country : Pakistan </p>
    <p class="render"> contact : +92 300 1234567</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

...but I wouldn't do this either: while it's slightly less breakable than using childNodes would be, it'd still depend on the order of the form elements never changing.

Instead of building dependencies on a particular layout into your code, I'd strongly recommend using specific identifiers (whether using the ID or a data attribute) for each specific form field.

Comment: Thanks Sir You are right that any change in HTML will cause errors in the type of implementation I needed.I was doing this because I was given this an assignment .Thank you very much for the answer